# Spring bean order of execution

Tags: java, spring

I have the following classes, main class and bean configuration file . The result of the program is also given. My question is that I am not getting the idea how this output is obtained? I don't understand the order in which this program gave an output. I thought in the third line of output there must be "constructing classB object" but the result shows "there is constructing classD object".

ClassA

```
public abstract class ClassA {
    private String text;

    public ClassA(){
        System.out.println("- new -");
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

ClassB

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public void settings(){
        System.out.println("Constructing ClassB object");
    }
}
```

ClassC

```
public class ClassC {
    private List<ClassA> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ClassA> getItems(){
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<ClassA> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void print(){
        String s = "This object contains: ";
        for(ClassA item : items){
            s+= item.getText();
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

ClassD

```
public class ClassD extends ClassA {
    public void settings(){
        System.out.println("Constructing ClassD Object");
    }
}
```

Main method is

```
public class Question1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(Question1Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("PREPARE");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new      ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springconfig.xml");
        System.out.println("BEGIN");
        ClassB classB = context.getBean("objectB",ClassB.class);
        ClassC classC = context.getBean("objectF",ClassC.class);
        System.out.println("END");
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Bean config file is

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="objectA" class="com.example.ClassA" abstract="true">
    <property name="text" value="Things!"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="objectB" class="com.example.ClassB" scope="prototype" parent="objectA"
    init-method="settings">
</bean>

<bean id="objectC" class="com.example.ClassD" scope="prototype" parent="objectA"
    init-method="settings">
</bean>

<bean id="objectD" class="com.example.ClassD" lazy-init="true" parent="objectA"
    init-method="settings">
</bean>

<bean id="objectE" class="com.example.ClassD" parent="objectA" init-method="settings"></bean>

<bean id="objectF" class="com.example.ClassC" init-method="print">
    <property name="items">
        <list>
            <ref bean="objectB"></ref>
            <bean class="com.example.ClassB">
                <property name="text" value="lot of things!"></property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The output of the program is :

```
PREPARE
-new-
constructing classD object
-new-
constructing classB object
-new-
This object contains : lots of things!
BEGIN
-new-
constructing classB object
END
```

Comment: too broad. what exactly you are confused about?

Comment: Why did you map com.example.ClassD multiple times i.e., for objectC & others ?

Comment: I am unable to understand the order in which this program gave an output? I thought in the third line of output there must be "constructing classB object" but the result shows "there is constructing classD object"

Comment: I know singleton creates single object and gave the same object reference to all but in case of prototype it creates new object whenever required.

Comment: Why did you expect "constructing classB object" ? can you give your reason then I can answer

Comment: Because lazy-init="true" is not there in bean objectB it means it is eager by default that's why it must be initialized while loading.

Comment: You are totally creating 3 instances for `com.example.ClassD` with references `objectC`, `objectD`, `objectE`, is it purposeful ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example well demonstrates the difference between the *singleton* and *prototype* scopes.

Instances of the first one will have been created *immediately the context is started up* and an IOC controller should support their entire lifecycle.

In contrast to the *singletons*, for the *prototype* scope, a container will create an instance by our demand. One request - a new well-configured object from a context is created. A container doesn't take care of such type of beans stopping thinking about them after giving away.

To put it simply, let's go through each statement:

1. `PREPARE` - context startup - the beginning of `singleton` initialisations
2. `constructing classD object` - it is a singleton
3. `constructing classB object` - the `objectF` is a singleton, there is a need to create a `ClassB` instance to initialise it
4. `BEGIN` - all singletons are bootstrapped
5. `constructing classB object` - due to  `context.getBean("objectB",ClassB.class);`

About the lazy initialization:

There are two `ClassD` singletons and likely they should be initialised by a container on the startup, but the last of them is marked with `lazy-init="false"` that prevents such behaviour. By the way, it is not a recommended practice because error detection on the compile time is always better than detection of them on during the runtime.

Comment: I got my answer. Thank you very much .